# Eigenvectors for a large symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, symbolic

I'm trying to compute the eigenvectors for a 42x42 symbolic matrix (with one variable) in Mathematica. I get the following error:

Eigenvectors::eivec0: Unable to find all eigenvectors. >>

and the answer is:zero

What could be a possible way to proceed?

Thanks.

my matrix is in this form: 
Matrix= {{-2.74685 + (11 j)/2, 0, -0.390857, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1.72219 + (11 j)/2, 0, -1.32891, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-0.390857, 
  0, -1.01642 + (11 j)/2, 0, -2.79771, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1.32891, 0, -0.528246 + (11 j)/2, 0, -4.66286, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2.79771, 
  0, -0.204268 + (11 j)/2, 0, -6.72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0}, {0, 0, 0, -4.66286, 0, -0.00765149 + (11 j)/2, 0, -8.736, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -6.72, 0, 
  0.0906785 + (11 j)/2, 0, -10.4832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8.736, 0, 0.115571 + (11 j)/2, 0, -11.7669, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10.4832, 0, 
  0.0894089 + (11 j)/2, 0, -12.4457, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -11.7669, 0, 0.0331231 + (11 j)/2, 0, -12.4457, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12.4457, 
  0, -0.0331231 + (11 j)/2, 0, -11.7669, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12.4457, 0, -0.0894089 + (11 j)/2, 0, -10.4832, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -11.7669, 
  0, -0.115571 + (11 j)/2, 0, -8.736, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10.4832, 0, -0.0906785 + (11 j)/2, 0, -6.72, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8.736, 0, 
  0.00765149 + (11 j)/2, 0, -4.66286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.72, 0, 0.204268 + (11 j)/2, 0, -2.79771, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4.66286, 0, 
  0.528246 + (11 j)/2, 0, -1.32891, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.79771, 0, 1.01642 + (11 j)/2, 0, -0.390857, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.32891, 0, 
  1.72219 + (11 j)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, -0.390857, 0, 2.74685 + (11 j)/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.3581 - 5 j, 0, 0., 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4.84175 - 5 j, 
  0, -0.390857, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.,
   0, -4.12192 - 5 j, 0, -1.32891, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, -0.390857, 0, -3.33864 - 5 j, 0, -2.79771, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.32891, 0, -2.71762 - 5 j, 
  0, -4.66286, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -2.79771, 0, -1.89062 - 5 j, 0, -6.72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4.66286, 0, -1.29051 - 5 j, 0, -8.736, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.72, 0, -0.796132 - 5 j,
   0, -10.4832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -8.736, 0, -0.417701 - 5 j, 0, -11.7669, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10.4832, 0, -0.161978 - 5 j, 0, -12.4457, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -11.7669, 
  0, -0.0331231 - 5 j, 0, -12.4457, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12.4457, 0, -0.0331231 - 5 j, 0, -11.7669, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -12.4457, 0, -0.161978 - 5 j,
   0, -10.4832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -11.7669, 0, -0.417701 - 5 j, 0, -8.736, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -10.4832, 0, -0.796132 - 5 j, 0, -6.72, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -8.736, 
  0, -1.29051 - 5 j, 0, -4.66286, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, -6.72, 0, -1.89062 - 5 j, 0, -2.79771, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4.66286, 0, -2.58124 - 5 j, 
  0, -1.32891, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -2.79771, 0, -3.33864 - 5 j, 0, -0.390857, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.32891, 0, -4.12192 - 5 j, 0, 0.}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.390857, 
  0, -4.84175 - 5 j, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0., 0, -5.808 - 5 j}} //MatrixForm

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your characterisitc equation is a 42-th degree polynomial? And you hope to find its roots? Unless it factors out into factors of degree 4 or less, "give up all hope, ye who enter here.."

Comment: yeh, is it imposible? can i solve it by other math programs? mathematica couldn't solve it.

Comment: Did give a proviso: "unless.."; Can you show us more detail?

Comment: Of course, I'll send you my matrix by editting The question.

Comment: You seem to mix exact integers with floating point. Try: `Eigensystem[mat/. j-> 1.0*j ]` ; I got a result in a few seconds using version 9.0. You could also have mentioned that your matrix is degree 1 in 'j' on the diagonal, and is all zero except at two above and below the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks I think that I must change the version of my mathematica it is 8 and I have the Previous error egain and all the eigenvectors are Zero.

Comment: have you tried the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Somayeh - have you tried just getting rid of the `//MatrixForm` command. That makes the head of `Matrix` into `MatrixForm` instead of `List`, which is what you need.

Comment: @  Wouter- yes, it is no problem in eigenvalues.

Comment: @Verbeia-yes, I tried it

Comment: @ Wouter- I changed the version and now i'm using mathematica in version 9.0. But I have the previous error yet.